# Which Redirect method should I use?

Tags: web-part, redirect

I'm using SharePoint 2010. I have webparts, then when OK/Save/Cancel etc is clicked, it will redirect a user to the relevant page.

Over the past few months of writing different WebParts I have checked over my code and see that I'm using different ways of redirecting the user. My question is, which is the correct one to use and why?

```
SPUtility.Redirect
Page.Response.Redirect
Context.Reponse.Redirect
```

Comment: I like that you asked this kind of question. Sometimes subtle differences like this can be the hardest thing to find concrete information on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I usually use SPUtility.Redirect when working with Application Pages or pages that need to potentially look at the source querystring or go back to settings.aspx.

If I am doing a redirect other times (usually in an HttpModule), I will use the Context.Response.Redirect or HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect.  The Page.Response.Redirect is just exposing the same object as Context.Response.Redirect, so they are essentially the same.

Comment: +1 for sharing relevant experience and putting the answer in context

Answer (score 11):

The difference between `SPUtility.Redirect` and `Page.Response.Redirect` is that `SPUtility.Redirect` provides many more options while redirecting. `SPUtility.Redirect` takes in the `SPRedirectFlags` enumeration as one of the parameters which gives us more control over the redirection. With it we can even keep the reference of the previous page.

More details on the `SPUtility.Redirect` over here:
https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20use%20SPUtility.Redirect.aspx

And as Steve said, `Page.Response.Redirect` and `Context.Response.Redirect` are the same object.

Comment: +1 for the reference link and the detail on the flags.